# Need help in restarting the app service remotely using the CICD pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-appservice

I have deployed the code to azure app service using azureWebAppPublish and did the swapping using azureWebAppSwapSlots. Does these 2 commands restart the app service on it's own or is there any specific command to do it using the Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Please elaborate it what's you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

Slots couses somtimes restart, so this is not related to Jenkins pipeline (probrbaly, as I don't see your pipeline). Please check this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#troubleshoot-swaps) where you have mentioned this:

> After slot swaps, the app may experience unexpected restarts. This is because after a swap, the hostname binding configuration goes out of sync, which by itself doesn't cause restarts. However, certain underlying storage events (such as storage volume failovers) may detect these discrepancies and force all worker processes to restart. To minimize these types of restarts, set the WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG=1 app setting on all slots. However, this app setting does not work with Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) apps.